Cancel package applied to large expressions
I am using the cancel package. When the expression is large, then the size of the strike becomes abnormally large. Here is an example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\begin{equation*}
\xcancel{\text{This is the long long long long expression that I want to cancel.}}
\end{equation*}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{document}

The problem:

I want the cross to have basically size as the expression it self. What should I do with it? Thanks!

I think the only mature approach to this issue is to acknowledge that the user macros of the cancel package -- \cancel, \bcancel, \xcancel, and \cancelto -- were not designed to be applied to overly long arguments.
If you really must "cancel" long strings, I suggest that you employ the soul package and its \st macro. Note that \st must be used in text mode, not math mode.

If you wanted to use \st isntead of \xcancel in the final row, you'd need to replace \xcancel{1+1=2} with \text{\st{\mbox{$1+1=2$}}}.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' environment
\usepackage{soul}    % for '\st' macro
\usepackage{cancel}  % for '\xcancel' macro

\begin{document}

\noindent
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\begin{gather*}
\text{This is the long long long long expression that I want to cancel.} \\
1+1=2 \\
\text{\st{This is the long long long long expression that I want to cancel.}} \\
\xcancel{1+1=2}
\end{gather*}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

\end{document}

